# Differential Amplifier constant output voltage

Tags: amplifier, differential

SE-Members,
The past few days i've been figuring out why my circuit does not work.
It is a simple differential amplifier with a gain of 2.
The OpAmp is the "TLE2027CDR".
My problem: The output voltage "v_out" is **always** at 3.57V. Even if both V1 and V2 are at ground potential.
By the way: V2 >=V1 of course.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fACj4I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Datasheet: https://www.component-hk.com/datasheets/ab/MAX9938TEUK+T.pdf
I couldn't find anything in the datasheet either.

Comment: Try to increase the Vcc voltage to large than 8V. Vcc_min = +/-4V (datasheet)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the Datasheet - page 5, table titled "recommended operating conditions".
The minimum supply voltage is +-4V - that's not 'approximately 4V', it's +4V and -4V (so 8V in total).

Then refer to the datasheet again - page 6, look for "Common-mode input voltage range", and you'll see it's typical values are -13V to +13V **with a +-15V supply**.
So now you know the input voltage isn't allowed any closer than 2V to either supply rail.

You need to either choose a different opamp, or increase your supply voltage significantly.

Comment: Oh wow, i am always impressed how fast experienced people can see the problems. I understand the  mistakes you mentioned now. The first one should've been noticed by myself. The second one is quite hidden in the datasheet for a novice i think. I guess i have to take another OpAmp then. Thankfully the pinmapping for Texas Instruments's OpAmps does not change much. How do you call OpAmps which are specially suited for non symmetrical powering: (+Vcc / GND) rail?

Comment: @TimB. "single supply" & "rail-to-rail" are the kinds of features you'd look for.